# Spark 2.0 - Databricks xml reader Input path does not exist

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am trying to use Databricks XML file reader api.

Sample code:

```
val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .master("local[*]")
    .appName("Java Spark SQL basic example")
    .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:///C:/TestData")
    .getOrCreate();
  //val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
  val df = spark.read
    .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
    .option("rowTag", "book")
    .load("books.xml")

    df.show()
```

If i give the file path directly , its looking for some warehouse directory. so i set the `spark.sql.warehouse.dir` option, but now it throws Input path does not exist.

It is actually looking under the project root directory , why is it looking for project root directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally its working.. We need to specify warehouse directory as well pass the absolute file path in the load method. I am not sure what is the use of warehouse directory.

The main part is we dont need to give **C:** as mentioned by other Stackoverflow answer.

**working code:**

```
val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .master("local[*]")
    .appName("Java Spark SQL basic example")
    .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:///TestData/")
    .getOrCreate();
  //val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
  val df = spark.read
    .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
    .option("rowTag", "book")
    .load("file:///TestData/books.xml")

    df.show()
```